# Null pointer when calling a method in a child class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting the `NullPointerException` in the `if (mBubbleView.intersects(tabPosX, tabPosY))` below, I don't know how to fix it, could you please help? Thanks.

public class BubbleActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = "Lab-Graphics";

// The Main view
private RelativeLayout mFrame;

// Bubble image's bitmap
private Bitmap mBitmap;

// Display dimensions
private int mDisplayWidth, mDisplayHeight;


// Gesture Detector
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

//BubbleView
private BubbleView mBubbleView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set up user interface
    mFrame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    // Load basic bubble Bitmap
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b64);

    Log.i(TAG, "Before setting up Gesture Detector");

    //Setup Gesture Detector
    setupGestureDetector();


    Log.i(TAG, "After setting up Gesture Detector");

} 
// Set up GestureDetector
private void setupGestureDetector() {

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,

    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        // If a single tap intersects a BubbleView, then pop the BubbleView
        // Otherwise, create a new BubbleView at the tap's location and add
        // it to mFrame. You can get all views from mFrame with ViewGroup.getChildAt()

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {

            // TODO - Implement onSingleTapConfirmed actions.
            // You can get all Views in mFrame using the
            // ViewGroup.getChildCount() method

            int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            float tabPosX = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            float tabPosY = event.getY(pointerIndex);

            mBubbleView = (BubbleView) mFrame.getChildAt(pointerIndex);
            Log.i(TAG, "pointerIndex: " + pointerIndex + " mFrame.getChildCount(): " + mFrame.getChildCount() + " mFrame.getChildAt(pointerIndex): " + mFrame.getChildAt(pointerIndex));

            Log.i(TAG, "mBubbleView is initiated:" + mBubbleView);
            if(mBubbleView.intersects(tabPosX, tabPosY)){
                Log.i(TAG, "If mBubbleView.intersects(tabPosX, tabPosY) = TRUE");
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG, "If mBubbleView.intersects(tabPosX, tabPosY) = FALSE");
                mBubbleView = new BubbleView(BubbleActivity.this,tabPosX,tabPosY);
                mFrame.addView(mBubbleView);
            }
            return true;
            //return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // TODO - Delegate the touch to the gestureDetector
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside onTouchEvent of the main View");
    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

// BubbleView is a View that displays a bubble.
// This class handles animating, drawing, and popping amongst other actions.
// A new BubbleView is created for each bubble on the display

public class BubbleView extends View {

    private static final int BITMAP_SIZE = 64;
    private static final int REFRESH_RATE = 40;
    private final Paint mPainter = new Paint();
    private ScheduledFuture<?> mMoverFuture;
    private int mScaledBitmapWidth;
    private Bitmap mScaledBitmap;

    // location, speed and direction of the bubble
    private float mXPos, mYPos, mDx, mDy, mRadius, mRadiusSquared;
    private long mRotate, mDRotate;

    BubbleView(Context context, float x, float y) {
        super(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside BubbleView constructor");
        // Create a new random number generator to
        // randomize size, rotation, speed and direction
        Random r = new Random();

        // Creates the bubble bitmap for this BubbleView
        createScaledBitmap(r);

        // Radius of the Bitmap
        mRadius = mScaledBitmapWidth / 2;
        mRadiusSquared = mRadius * mRadius;

        // Adjust position to center the bubble under user's finger
        mXPos = x - mRadius;
        mYPos = y - mRadius;

    }

    private void createScaledBitmap(Random r) {

        if (speedMode != RANDOM) {
            mScaledBitmapWidth = BITMAP_SIZE * 3;

        } else {
            //TODO - set scaled bitmap size in range [1..3] * BITMAP_SIZE
            int min = 1;
            int max = 3;

            mScaledBitmapWidth = (r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min)*BITMAP_SIZE;


        }

        // TODO - create the scaled bitmap using size set above
        //mFrame.addView(mBubbleView);
        mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, mScaledBitmapWidth, mScaledBitmapWidth, false);
    }

    // Returns true if the BubbleView intersects position (x,y)
    private synchronized boolean intersects(float x, float y) {

        // TODO - Return true if the BubbleView intersects position (x,y)
        return false;
    }

    // Cancel the Bubble's movement
    // Remove Bubble from mFrame
    // Play pop sound if the BubbleView was popped
```

}

This is full LogCat:

```
08-08 19:48:55.145: I/Lab-Graphics(2318): Before setting up Gesture Detector
08-08 19:48:55.186: I/Lab-Graphics(2318): After setting up Gesture Detector
08-08 19:48:55.194: D/OpenGLRenderer(2318): Render dirty regions requested: true
08-08 19:48:55.194: D/(2318): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0d4d60, tid 2318
08-08 19:48:55.222: D/Atlas(2318): Validating map...
08-08 19:48:55.283: D/(2318): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6b10110, tid 2333
08-08 19:48:55.426: I/OpenGLRenderer(2318): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-08 19:48:55.591: D/OpenGLRenderer(2318): Enabling debug mode 0
08-08 19:48:55.661: W/EGL_emulation(2318): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-08 19:48:55.661: W/OpenGLRenderer(2318): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae0e5da0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-08 19:49:00.246: I/Lab-Graphics(2318): Inside onTouchEvent of the main View
08-08 19:49:00.439: I/Lab-Graphics(2318): Inside onTouchEvent of the main View
08-08 19:49:00.558: I/Lab-Graphics(2318): Inside onSingleTapConfirmed of the Gesture Detector
08-08 19:49:00.558: I/Lab-Graphics(2318): mNoOfChildViews: 0
08-08 19:49:00.559: I/Lab-Graphics(2318): pointerIndex: 0 mFrame.getChildCount(): 0 mFrame.getChildAt(pointerIndex):
null
08-08 19:49:00.559: I/Lab-Graphics(2318): mBubbleView is initiated:null
08-08 19:49:00.559: D/AndroidRuntime(2318): Shutting down VM
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): Process: course.labs.graphicslab, PID: 2318
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke direct method 'boolean
course.labs.graphicslab.BubbleActivity$BubbleView.intersects(float, float)' on a null object reference
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at
course.labs.graphicslab.BubbleActivity$BubbleView.access$0(BubbleActivity.java:368)
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at
course.labs.graphicslab.BubbleActivity$1.onSingleTapConfirmed(BubbleActivity.java:185)
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at
android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:273)
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
08-08 19:49:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-08 19:49:03.120: I/Process(2318): Sending signal. PID: 2318 SIG: 9
```

This is main.xml. The mBubbleView is created programatically when user click to the screen (mFrame in this case).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF444444"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post `main.xml` your `mBubbleView` is null.

Comment: This is the full logcat:

Comment: Check if there is a BubbleView in your main.xml. Also, we can't see your main.xml (not linked)

Comment: I'm sorry, here it is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF444444"
    android:id="@+id/frame">
 
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: `mBubbleView.intersects(tabPosX, tabPosY))` <= You are testing for intersection on an object that does not exist. The comment actually mentions that you need to check the existence of a `BubbleView` but you never do the check. I also don't know what `mFrame.getChildAt(pointerIndex)` is supposed to achieve. This starts to look like an assignment question with the comments not written by you.

Comment: Thanks. The mFrame.getChildAt is just a step to debug. So you said I need to check the existence of the mBubbleView. I can do that to avoid the Fatal Error by:

Comment: int temp = mFrame.getChildCount(); For(int i=0; i<temp; i++){ mBubbleView = mFrame.getChildAt(i); if (mBubbleView!=null) {call interests...}} But still, mBubbleView is null so it doesn't go into the if clause. mBubbleView is created programtically, do you think I have to declare it in main.xml like another buddy said below?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put bubble view in your xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF444444"
    android:id="@+id/frame">
    <com.your.package.BubbleView id="@+id/bubbleView"></com.your.package.BubbleView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your onCreate you take that bubble view by id

```
bubbleView = (BubbleView)findViewById(R.id.bubbleView); //your xml bubble view id
```